# assign values to named dataframe columns from named vector

Tags: r, assign

Lets suppose I have a vector and a dataframe:

```
v <- c(2,2,4,5,6)
names(v) <- c("F", "J", "D", "A", "B")

df<- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 1)), c("A" ,"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))
```

I now want to assign values stored in `v` to the matching column of `df`. A "match" would be indicated, that names of `v` and columnnames of 'df' are indentical.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can directly subset the columns from `names` and assign value

```
df[names(v)] <- v
df
#  A B  C D  E F  G  H  I J
#1 5 6 NA 4 NA 2 NA NA NA 2
```

Comment: thanks! It seems I was overthinking my problem, thats way too easy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match`:

```
df[match(names(v), names(df))] <- v
```